# Java - Spring AOP - stop method from execution using before advice?

Tags: java, spring, aop

How can I use before advice as security measure in Spring AOP.

For example I have this before advice(with pseudo code):

```
@Before("trigger()")
public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint point){
    Method[] a = point.getSignature().getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            //if method has such arguments then
        if(a[i] 'has args String name, String role, Int Money'){ 
               //And if these arguments meets such requirements
                if(a[i].argument(Int.class) > 1000 or a[i].argument(String role).equals("normal"))
                    //Stop executing this method
                    a[i].stop
                }
    }
}
```

I know this is just pseudo code, so it may not look correct, but I hope you get an idea. Is there some JoinPoint method to stop scanned method if it meets or does not meets some requirements?

Comment: IF it is a security measure throw an exception.

Comment: You can choose not to call `proceed()`.

Answer (score 5):

How about just throwing an Exception?

```
if (!isAllowed) {
  throw new NotAuthorizedException(..)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

```
@Before("trigger()")
public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint point){
    Method[] a = point.getSignature().getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            //if method has such arguments then
        if(a[i] 'has args String name, String role, Int Money'){ 
               //And if these arguments meets such requirements
                if(a[i].argument(Int.class) > 1000 or a[i].argument(String role).equals("normal"))
                     throw new Exception("Operation Not allowed");
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically in that link states that you cannot? Also what is the point of your code sample, is it something that would not work, or a workaround to achieve the behavior desired in the question?